# Moles of Sodium Peroxoborate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, stoichiometry

> The question involves the addition of $\pu{0.15 g}$ of an already prepared sample of sodium peroxoborate which is added to $\pu{100 mL}$ of $\pu{1 M}$ $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\pu{2 g}$ of $\ce{KI}$. The solution is left to stand for 10 minutes and is then titrated against standardized sodium thiosulfate. Starch indicator was used and a titration figure of $\pu{17.1 mL}$  was obtained. Find the moles of sodium peroxoborate.

Sodium peroxoborate, sulfuric acid and potassium iodide react as follows:

$$\ce{Na2[B2(OH)4(O2)2] + 4 KI + 3 H2SO4 -> Na2SO4 + 2 K2SO4 + B2O3 + 5 H2O + 2 I2}$$
Iodide reacts with thiosulfate as follows :

$$\ce{I2 + 2 [S2O3]^2- -> 2 I- + [S4O6]^2-}$$

I'm not sure how to use the titration value to find the result of this answer. I'm not looking for the solution I just need a point in the direction that will help me at least get a start on the problem.

What about this:

$$2 \, \text{mol} \, \ce{S2O3 ->} 1 \, \text{mol}  \, \ce{I}$$

when we made the sodium thiosulfate I calculated the moles to be $0.096 \, \text{mol/L}$. Hence

$$0.096 \, \text{mol/L} \, \, \ce{S2O3->} 0.048 \, \text{mol/L}  \, \, \ce{I}$$.

the relationship between iodine and peroxoborate is as follows:

$$4 \, \text{mol} \, \ce{I->} 1 \, \text{mol}  \, \ce{[B_2(O2)2(OH)4]}$$

Hence

$$0.048 \, \text{mol/L} \, \, \ce{I->} 0.012 \, \text{mol/L}  \, \, \ce{[B_2(O2)2(OH)4]}$$.

But I didn't use the titration value of thiosulfate in this solution?

Comment: Well, you can use the amount of thiosulfate to compute the amount of iodine. You can use the amount of iodine to compute the amount of peroxyborate. There are stoichiometric relationships between all of those.

Comment: Can I say $\text{moles} = \frac{2}{166}=0.012 \, $ mol $\ce{KI}$

Comment: Because I'm struggling to see why I  can't just say $\frac{0.15}{307.62}= 4.88 \times 10^{-4}$ mol where $307.62$ is the $M_r$ of peroxoborate.

Comment: How many moles of thiosulfate react with 1 mole of iodine? How many moles of peroxoborate react with 1 mole of iodine? You can't solve these types of problems without understanding the stoichiometric relationships. Nowhere in your solution do these ratios come into play...

Comment: This problem is out of whack. You stated "standardized sodium thiosulfate" but then you don't give a concentration for the thiosulfate. Just knowing how many ml of solution was used doesn't define the number of moles of thiosulfate. The sulfuric acid and KI would be in excess so knowing how much of those doesn't help. The only way to solve with the information given is to use the weight of the sodium peroxoborate. IS THAT THE POINT OF THE PROBLEM!?!

Comment: I edited the question, I'm still unsure as to whether the solution is correct or not.

Comment: Amounts correlate directly, not concentrations. You are missing the core point if stoichiometry, which is that the balanced equation provided ratios between amount of substance, e.g., number of moles. That ratio does not apply to mass or concentration.

Comment: But I don't have the amount of moles of thiosulfate, all I have then is the titration value.